# Getting ODBC error in remote server, but localhost works - Django-mssql-backend

Tags: python, django

I'm deploying a Django app in IIS, but I'm getting the following error:

('IM002', '[IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')

[image]

my settings.py has the following:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'sql_server.pyodbc',
        'NAME': 'DatabaseName',
        'HOST': 'HOSTNAME',
        'USER': 'username',
        'PASSWORD': 'password',
        'OPTIONS': {
            'driver': 'ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server',
            'collation': 'SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS',
            'SERVER': 'Hostname',
            'DATABASE': 'DatabaseName',
        }
    }
}
```

with this configuratio it works when I run it in my dev environment, but when I move it to deploy it doesn't work, not even when I do a **manage.py runserver**
I have installed the following packages:

django
django-filter
django-msssql-backend
pyodbc

how can I troubleshoot? in my dev enviroment connects to the same database and server, but in the deployed location it just gives the error when trying to do runserver command.

I'm connecting to a Sql server version:
"Microsoft SQL Server 2014 - 12.0.2548.0 (X64)"

I have Django 3.2.4
Python 3.9.5
Django-mssql-backend 2.8.1

Comment: Is your dev environment also IIS?

Comment: no, but in this case the error occurs when I do runserver on the remote server, so it would be in the same situation as the dev environment

Comment: Are you certain the ODBC Driver for SQL Server is installed on the problem server? And why are you using ODBC Driver 13 instead of ODBC Driver 17?

Comment: jesus... I was missinng the driver in the server.. (and I changed to 17).

Comment: I don't know if I should leave this as reference to anyone that has similar problem, (although a very dumb problem) or delete the question

Comment: Guaranteed, someone will have the same problem.  I've added an answer to the same effect.  You may also want to look at mssql-django, the Microsoft-maintained fork of django-mssql-backend, currently in beta.

Comment: I'll keep an eye on that fork, it's interesting :) I'm new to django, but enjoying the learning

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That error indicates that the driver you've listed can't be found on the server.
So install the driver on the target server.